# Difference between copy_n and copy

Tags: c++, difference

Difference between following? Which one has undefined behavior? Both?

```
std::copy_n(asdf.begin(), asdf.size(), asdf.begin());
std::copy(asdf.begin(), asdf.end(), asdf.begin());
```

Assume a `std::vector<int>` is given to the function. And the two functions are not the same like some people are saying.

Is this a defect in the standard?

Comment: They both can have undefined behavior.  One copies by quantity, the other by range.

Comment: Which one in the above has undefined behavior? Not just functions.

Comment: If you supply a size larger than your memory, the `copy_n` will have undefined behavior.  If the `end()` or `begin()` iterators in the `copy` are out of bounds, you will have undefined behavior.  It's both, depending on the values supplied to the functions.

Comment: It'll depend on the type that `asdf` stores. If the type has undefined behaviour on self assignment, then that's the kind of behaviour you get from either line. Otherwise both of the above have defined behaviour.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How can begin and end iterators be out of range?

Comment: And the fact that the three of you have inconsistent answers shows how nobody knows the answer

Comment: How can this be "too broad"? The answer, whatever it may be, is straight-forward. I am up-voting because it is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @NeilKirk It's too broad because it's unanswerable without knowing the values given to the function.

Comment: @Falmarri Ok technically the question should be clarified, but come on. You know what it is asking. It's reasonable to assume `asdf` is a standard container or a suitably compatible one.

Answer (score 7):

```
std::copy_n(asdf.begin(), asdf.size(), asdf.begin());
```

This is not undefined behavior. `copy_n` only requires that `[first, first + n)` and `[result, result + n)` be valid ranges. With the arguments you've passed, you've guaranteed that they are. (*I am assuming `asdf` is a standard container, or a container with similar behavior. I am also assuming that the contained type has a well behaved assignment operator*)

```
std::copy(asdf.begin(), asdf.end(), asdf.begin());
```

This has undefined behavior. For `std::copy`, `result` must not be in the range `[first, last)`

Comment: You are saying `copy_n` can self-copy but `copy` can't? I didn't know that. Why is that?

Comment: @NeilKirk: I don't know why. But that's what the standard says. `copy` lists this requirement directly, and `copy_n` does not.

Comment: @NeilKirk Because the standard (*[alg.copy]*) says so? Possibly so that `copy` can delegate to `memcpy` for trivially copyable types. There's `copy_backward` if you want overlapping ranges where the start of the output range overlaps the source range to be handled.

Comment: @Praetorian But `copy_n` shouldn't delegate to `memcpy`?

Comment: @NeilKirk Speculating ... `copy_n` needs to keep a count, so it can't resort to bulk memory copying like `copy` can.

Comment: Is it defect in the standard maybe?

Comment: @Praetorian `memcpy` also needs a count.

Comment: @NeilKirk True, but that's trivially computable given random access iterators for instance. I know that still doesn't explain the differences in preconditions, and I don't have a better answer. It could just be that `copy_n` is meant to be the general purpose option that handles overlapping ranges without the caller having to do validation checks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n _"Overlap of ranges is not permitted."_